# Besides hospital prices, what data-transparency bills have been passed in the last two adminstrations?

Tags: united-states, legislation, transparency

I remember the [Trump-era law that required hospitals to publish their prices](https://www.cms.gov/newsroom/press-releases/cms-completes-historic-price-transparency-initiative).

In the Trump or Biden administration, were there any other similar bills that required other agencies or businesses to publish previously-hidden data?

Comment: FYI, the price transparency rule was the result of [Executive Order 13877](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2019/06/27/2019-13945/improving-price-and-quality-transparency-in-american-healthcare-to-put-patients-first) rather than as an act of Congress.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what relevance your framing has. Besides the fact that Biden's presidency isn't even a year in, legislation generally depends on who controls Congress. POTUS can veto, but on stuff like this it's hard to see why they would bother, unless it impinged on some executive privilege.

Comment: And if you're trying to gauge how transparent an administration has been, there are probably more relevant measures, like how many requests they approved or denied https://www.washingtonpost.com/outlook/2021/05/29/executive-privilege-immunity-biden-trump/ Making transparacy with somebody else's data (e.g. the healthcare companies') is a somewhat marginal measure of government transparency.... if that's what you were trying to get at.